# Googlesheet - How to skip empty cell in macro loop and continue filled cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

would greatly appreciate if anyone is able to help!

I am working on editing a macro that involves vlookup copy/paste data from Worksheet A (IB) to Worksheet B (Inbound POs). However, it copies empty cell in Worksheet A and overwrites the filled cell in Worksheet B which i do not want. Anyone able to help? Code below:

```
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === 'IB' && editedCol === 4 && editedRowStart > 1) {
var ibSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('IB')
var ibSheetData = ibSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
var updatedPOs = []
var updatedDates = []
for (var i = editedRowStart - 1; i < editedRowEnd; i++) {
updatedPOs.push(ibSheetData[1])
updatedDates.push(ibSheetData[3])
}
var updatedObject = Object.assign(...updatedPOs.map((PO, i) => ({[PO]: updatedDates})))
var inboundPOSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Inbound POs')
var inboundPOSheetLastRow = inboundPOSheet.getLastRow()
var inboundPOSheetData = inboundPOSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
for (var i = 1; i < inboundPOSheetLastRow; i++) {
var inboundPO = inboundPOSheetData[1]
if (updatedPOs.includes(inboundPOSheetData[1])) {
inboundPOSheet.getRange(i+1, 19).setValue(updatedObject[inboundPO])
}
}
} SummarySheet.getRange(36,3).setValue(currentDate);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. You want to copy some data from `IB` to `Inbound POs`, but you'd like to (1) avoid copying when some cells (which ones??) in the row are empty, and (2) not overwrite existing data in `Inbound POs`, but append data to the first empty row maybe? Can you please clarify all this? Maybe some visual information could be useful for understanding the expected outcome (screenshots? copy of the spreadsheet?)

Comment: Hello @lamblichus that is correct, i am trying to copy date from 'Actual Delivery Date' in IB tab to the corresponding PO 'Actual Delivery Date' in the Inbound PO tab but i do not want it to do that for empty cells in IB tab. Images are as below. 

![Valid XHTML](D:\Users\pkoh\Pictures\IB tab.PNG).
![Valid XHTML](D:\Users\pkoh\Pictures\Inbound Pos tab.PNG).

Comment: Hi, you didn't provide valid links to these screenshots. Please consider editing your question and adding them, it's much easier to add images that way (see [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491)).